# WebStorm 2018 Project pane: how to change font color?

Tags: fonts, colors, settings, webstorm

In my WebStorm 2018 IDE I do not use any theme. 
My problem is that the folder names in the project paneare marked with a clear black font, 
and the filenames are very light, difficult to distinguish on the background. 
In the Settings > Editor menu, I could not find the appropriate setting.

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your question

Answer (score 1):

Check **Settings | Version Control | File Status Colors** - file color likely indicates a certain VCS status